# Which manga was it that a boy went out to take revenge for a witch the kingdom executed?

Tags: story-identification, manga

Ok, so I don't remember much about this manga since I read it around quite a long time ago (probably ~1 year ago). But this boy was raised by a witch. He was taught the ways of witches by this really kind witch (spells and stuff). Just saying, I think he was an orphan before the witch found him.

Also, the kingdom hated witches or something. So one day the witch was caught and executed in the public. After that event, the boy started out on a journey for revenge. That's all I remember.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is "*The Kingdoms of Ruin*".

The first chapter has a young boy, raised by a witch. The witch taught the boy magic, or it is at least mentioned that he can use it. They were attacked by forces from the Lydia Empire, and end up in a situation where the witch cannot use magic. The empire then kills her and the boy is taken captive, swearing vengeance.

The second chapter has him escape and begin a rampage of revenge.

Comment: Yes! That is it, thank you!